# How do I add auto-complete comment in Xcode (Swift)?

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation

How can I add text to autocomplete like below, the "Tells the element to activate itself..." part,

[image]

This is what I have,

[image]

But the "This is a test" part doesn't show up in autocomplete,

[image]

**Please do not link to other posts that cover how to write comments so that they would show up in the window that pops up with Option+Click, I'm well-aware of how to do that. My question is specifically around comments showing up in the auto-complete window.**

Answer (score 6):

try this, tested on Xcode 9.3 - 9.4 beta and swift 4.1

```
/// this is printName func and will print your name
func printName(name: String){
   print("my name is \(name)")
}
```

and result :
[image]

Comment: Is it `///` three comments that do it? Or would `//` two in the same position work as well?

Answer (score 2):

```
    /**
     Put comments just above the funcion using the Markdown format like this
    */
    func exampleFunction() {
        print("The comments above will show up in the auto complete popover.")
    }
```

[Popover Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmnjE.png)

[Full explanation @ Hacking With Swift](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwin9pKM6d7hAhVCS6wKHSYIBmwQFjABegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hackingwithswift.com%2Fexample-code%2Flanguage%2Fhow-to-add-markdown-comments-to-your-code&usg=AOvVaw2DFAlpmrXpXepqcE04r38v)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish is unfortunately not possible anymore.

The reason is that the autocomplete popover does not show comments from class files but instead searches in a separate doc-set generated by Apple.

I added a more complete description here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43982094/1415898

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot and it seems that this feature does not support for self-created functions. all you have is just the popup info window for your functions :(

Comment: Based on Apple's own [Swift Documentation Markup Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/) it should be possible though. It says: *Markup for Swift symbols is used for Quick Help and for the description shown in symbol completion.*

Answer (score 0):

**Update on Xcode 14.3.1** it's now possible to add comment on autocompletion popover just adding a single line comment to the property like in example below

```swift
extension CGFloat {
    /// A size of 0 points
    static let sizing0x = CGFloat(0)
    /// A size of 2 points
    static let sizing0xHalf = CGFloat(2)
    /// A size of 1 points
    static let sizing0xQuarter = CGFloat(1)
    /// A size of 4 points
    static let sizing1x = CGFloat(4)
    /// A size of 6 points
    static let sizing1xHalf = CGFloat(6)
    /// A size of 8 points
    static let sizing2x = CGFloat(8)
    /// A size of 12 points
    static let sizing3x = CGFloat(12)
    /// A size of 14 points
    static let sizing3xHalf = CGFloat(14)
    /// A size of 16 points
    static let sizing4x = CGFloat(16)
}
```

now you can see in the screenshot below the comment while typing.

[image]