# Xcode 8.2.1 not showing documentation description on autocomplete

Tags: swift, xcode, autocomplete, swift3, documentation

I'm having problems adding documentation to my code in Xcode 8.2.1.

Here's my code:

```
/// Test documentation method
///
/// - Parameter string: The input string
/// - Returns: The output bool
func testMethod(string:String) -> Bool {

    if string == "YES" {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

The documentation shows as expected in the quick help window but the description doesn't show in the code autocomplete window.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to get the description to show in the autocomplete box as in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Still doesn't work for me in Xcode 9b1. Doesn't look like it will work anytime soon :(

Comment: Any solution you got for your problem? I am looking for Apple's UILabel method's only but still not coming :/

Answer (score 3):

You are right, the descriptions you added to the top of your methods and properties don't appear in the popover anymore.

As noted, you can only see the descriptions of Apple's own methods and properties.
The reason being that Xcode doesn't parse these from their classes but rather from a separate documentation set (which you can find in Xcode's `Help/Documentation and API reference` tab).

So unless Apple decides to change this, I'm afraid it won't be possible to see your own in the popover.

You could keep an eye on existing doc set generators ([AppleDoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc), [Jazzy](https://github.com/realm/jazzy)), maybe they'll offer a way to link their documentation to Xcode's popover.

Keep in mind that you do see your own comments when opening the quick help popover with <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> on a method or property.

Answer (score 1):

For me the best way to resolve this is by cleaning the project Shift+Command+K, and if that is not working, it is a god idea to remove Derived Data folder.

To remove this folder go to Xcode preferences, Locations tab[image: Derived Data folder location]

and click on the small arrow to open a finder, and remove manually the folder.

Restart Xcode, and check if now is working

Comment: Just tried cleaning the project and deleting the Derived Data folder. After restarting Xcode the documentation still only shows on the quick help section.

Answer (score -2):

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/MarkupFunctionality.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH54-SW1

please refer the official documentation