# How do i show auto-completion comment in XCode8 (Swift3)

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, comments

[How do I add auto-complete comment in XCode (Swift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517798/how-do-i-add-auto-complete-comment-in-xcode-swift)

Same question.

[image]

option + click is working.

But In auto-complition, can't see.

How do I do ?